# Connecting to Azure PostgreSQL using domain user account through QGIS

Tags: qgis, database, connection, azure

We are using QGIS over the top of an Azure PostgreSQL database.  We have it working using SQL user / password combination but security policy dictates this should be a domain user authenticated connection.

Can you connect to an Azure PostgreSQL database using a domain user account through QGIS?